Rewrite bash to Saltstack
I am writing a Saltstack .sls file. This file will be executed with:
sudo salt-run state.orchestrate <file name> pillar="{environment: dev}
So, everything will be run on the salt-master.
I need to do the following.

I need to fetch hostnames of all minions that have a grain "environment" that is equal to the pillar "environment" and they have a "roles" grain that is equal to "mod-web".
For all these fetched hosts, I need to fetch the corresponding port (the hostname is the glob target) so I would like to iterate through the fetched hosts and fetch their port. The port is inside a pillar "mod:web:port".
After having these two informations, I would like to do an http request (but not using cmd.run).

This was previously done in a shell script, but I want to move it completely to this .sls file. Here is the shell script:
for HOST in $(sudo salt -C "G@environment:dev and G@roles:mod-web" config.get fqdn --output=text | awk '{ print $2 }')
do
    PORT=$(sudo salt $HOST pillar.get mod:web:port --output=text | awk '{ print $2 }')
    while [ ! $(curl -sfX GET http://${HOST}:${PORT}/api/__health --noproxy "*") ]; do sleep 1; done
    echo "mod-web @$HOST OK"
done


This appears to be a basic health check. Not some state change that needs orchestration. Why are you trying to use orchestration states to do it?

Using Salt to instead install and configure an actual monitoring system would be a much better use of resources, than trying to build one out of Salt itself.

For the last part to make the http request
see https://ansible-cn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/states/writing.html to write a custom state module and simply write a python function to make a http call. You use salt utils or the salt http execution module https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/http.html or can use python requests library or any other way you write python code to make an http request. Then declare your state in your sls using the custom state module. Alternately you can just call the salt http execution module directly using module.run (https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html) but then it is not idempotent and will always say that the state changed, so my recommendation is to create a state module if you can.

As the task has nothing to do with effecting a state, a state module is not the right choice.

It may have to do something with affecting a state. The question does not have enough context to know why the http call is getting the health status and waiting for it. It looks like perhaps another state kicked of creating some kind of services and this is trying to wait for the service to actually be listening. Using loop.until (https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.loop.html) may be another option.
